# What does QD4 mean in context of SSD performance?

Tags: ssd, benchmarking

I'm looking at various SSD benchmarks and found that they sometimes specify the "QD4 random read" performance. What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](http://linustechtips.com/main/topic/398616-4k-random-qd1-and-qd32/?p=5384883) seems to shed some light on that:

> QD means "queue depth" and simply indicates the number of separate threads taking place with the drive while each thread independently runs its own transfers. QD4 means there are 4 separate threads that are going on the specific drive. These are 4 separate requests for 4K of data. I'd say that a regular user with everyday usage is closer to 1-3 depth so the QD4 might be more relevant. You can find this out in Resource Monitor in the Disk Tap where a graph of your queue depth is displayed by default on the right side.

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/q/1049382/100154